# How can I pick highest 3 string values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array which has `sequence number`. I want to pick top 3 `sequence numbers` from array based not sequence number only like   `"sequesnce": "9.80.709.5` This is my array

```
array1=[
{
    "orgId": 101,
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
    "sequesnce": "6.408.06.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR"
},
{
    "orgId": 102,
    "dId": 442,
    "name": "Test2",
    "sequesnce": "9.80.709.5 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
},
{
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "9.138.309.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/03/2019 (Sections: P4.45600) Spain HR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
},
{
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "8.208.409.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 10/03/2019 (Sections: P4.568787) Spain HR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
},
{
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "9.408.90.3 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
},
```

I am looking for output

```
topThree=
{
"sequesnce": "9.80.709.5 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
},
{
"sequesnce": "9.408.90.3 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
},
{
"sequesnce": "9.138.309.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/03/2019 (Sections: P4.45600) Spain HR",
},
```

I tried this

```
function arrayMax(arr) {
return arr.reduce(function (p, v) {
  return ( p > v ? p : v );
});
}]

var maximo = arrayMax(obj); //return the high
```

This returns me

```
{
    "orgId": 102,
    "dId": 442,
    "name": "Test2",
    "sequesnce": "9.80.709.5 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
},
```

This code return single array not three and not sure in all cases this logic going to work.

Comment: Why is `9.80.709.5` the maximum and not `9.408.90.3`?

Comment: @Nick -  `9.408.90.3` is old release than `9.80.709.5`

Comment: I guess I don't understand your numbering system... I would have thought `9.408.xxx` was *newer* than `9.80.xxx`

Comment: @Nick - The way you said its correct. I was confused.

Comment: Will sequence ALWAYS be 1.1.1.1 to 999.999.999.999? Or could there be a 999.999

Comment: @mplungjan - I am not completely understanding your comment. Could you please write more.

Comment: See my answer - if the sequence string is shorter but the first value is higher, localeCompare won't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sort with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and take an options to sort by columns of dotted values.

At the end take the top three items with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
const
    array = [{ orgId: 101, dId: 494, name: "Test1", sequesnce: "6.408.06.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR" }, { orgId: 102, dId: 442, name: "Test2", sequesnce: "9.80.709.5 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR" }, { orgId: 103, sequesnce: "9.138.309.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/03/2019 (Sections: P4.45600) Spain HR", dId: 494, name: "Test3" }, { orgId: 103, sequesnce: "8.208.409.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 10/03/2019 (Sections: P4.568787) Spain HR", dId: 494, name: "Test3" }, { orgId: 103, sequesnce: "9.408.90.3 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR", dId: 494, name: "Test3" }],
    top3 = array
        .sort((a, b) => b.sequesnce.localeCompare(a.sequesnce, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }))
        .slice(0, 3)

console.log(top3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great solution as long as the sequence is 1.1.1.1 to 999.999.999.999 and not suddenly 999.999

Comment: @R15, you need to take an object, maybe take `Object.values(yourObject)` and sort it with the above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand the tuples before sorting if you have shorter sequences with higher leading values - that will not work with localeCompare

```js
const maxLen = 4;
const expandTuple = tpl => {
  tpl = tpl.split('.');
  while (tpl.length < maxLen) tpl.unshift("000");
  return tpl.map(x => x.padStart(3, "0")).join('.');
};
const array1 = [{ "orgId": 101, "dId": 494, "name": "Test1",
    "sequence": "6.408.06.0 Sequence Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR" },{"orgId": 102,"dId": 442,"name": "Test2",
    "sequence": "9.80.709.5 Sequence Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",},{"orgId": 103,
    "sequence": "99.1.1 NOTE THIS IS SHORTER Sequence Date : Mon 06/03/2019 (Sections: P4.45600) Spain HR","dId": 494,"name": "Test3",},{"orgId": 103,
    "sequence": "8.208.409.0 Sequence Date : Mon 10/03/2019 (Sections: P4.568787) Spain HR","dId": 494,"name": "Test3",},{"orgId": 103,
    "sequence": "9.408.90.3 Sequence Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR","dId": 494,   "name": "Test3",  }
]


const three = array1.sort((a,b) => {
  const aTub = a.sequence.split(" ")[0];
  const bTub = b.sequence.split(" ")[0];
  if (expandTuple(aTub)<expandTuple(bTub)) return 1
  if (expandTuple(aTub)>expandTuple(bTub)) return -1
  return 0;
}).slice(0,3)
console.log(three)

// ---- compare other solution which fails on the shorter sequence

console.log(array1
  .sort((a, b) => b.sequence.localeCompare(a.sequence, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }))
  .slice(0, 3)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, using `Array.map`, you can generate the array of `sequesne` item objects only.
- And using `Array.sort`, you can sort the array by descending order.
- And using `Array.splice`, you can extract the top 3 items from the sorted array.

```js
const array1 = [{
    "orgId": 101,
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
    "sequesnce": "6.408.06.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR"
  },
  {
    "orgId": 102,
    "dId": 442,
    "name": "Test2",
    "sequesnce": "9.80.709.5 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/04/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "9.138.309.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 06/03/2019 (Sections: P4.45600) Spain HR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "8.208.409.0 Sequesnce Date : Mon 10/03/2019 (Sections: P4.568787) Spain HR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 103,
    "sequesnce": "9.408.90.3 Sequesnce Date : Mon 08/06/2019 (Sections: P4.00344) Italy CR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
  }
];

const sortedArr = array1.map(({ sequesnce }) => ({ sequesnce })).sort((a, b) => (b.sequesnce.localeCompare(a.sequesnce, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})));

const topCount = 3;
console.log(sortedArr.splice(0, topCount));
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct results. See OPs comments to the question.